# mysql insert not working on online server (Godaddy Linux Hosting)

Tags: php, mysql

Insertion through PHP in MySQL is working properly on localhost, but when I uploaded it on Linux Hosting it's not working and also not giving any error. I used this code in many places and it was working perfectly, but it's not working here.

GitHub link: https://github.com/loveleenkaurnancy/parttimepoints

```php
<?php
include("header.php");

@$id=$_SESSION['id'];
if($id == "") {
} else {
  echo "<script>window.open('home.php', '_self')</script>";
}

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $password = md5($_POST['password']);
  $q = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM REGISTER where email ='$email'");
  if(mysqli_num_rows($q) > 0) {
    $msg2 = "Email Already Registered";
  } else {
    $query = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO REGISTER(name, email, password) values ('$name', '$email', '$password')");

    if($query) {
      $msg1 = "Registered Successfully";
    } else {
      $msg2 = "Error";
    }
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: MySQL returns errors differently than regular PHP. You need to explicitly check for [mysqli errors](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php).

Comment: You are wide open for SQL injection. Since you're using mysqli, take advantage of [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php). **This will take care of any pesky quoting issues that may occur.**

Comment: If you are using this for anything other than your own education, don't ever, ever try to write your own user authentication code. What you have would be hacked apart and even without a hack your database exposed to untold mischief. People much smarter than either of us have created libraries that are at least mostly secure for the moment.

Comment: Having written the above, you could help us answer your question by saying what you have tried and what the results were. Does `$_POST` have the values you expect?